# Create widget with known AppWidgetProviderInfo

Tags: android, widget, appwidgetprovider

Instead of showing the user a list of widget provider, I let him select one and then configure the widget, I manually load all widget providers and let the user drag and drop those widgets in my app.
As soon as the user drops such an icon, I want to create and configure this widget. How do I do this?

**Code with comments**

```
// 1) get a list of all app widget providers
List<AppWidgetProviderInfo> providers = mAppWidgetManager.getInstalledProviders();

// 2) Display the list to the user and let him select a widget provider => done via custom UI

// 3) handle the user selected widget and create it
// 3.1) create new widget id 
int appWidgetId = mAppWidgetHost.allocateAppWidgetId();
// 3.2) configure widget
// ??? How do I do this now? appWidgetInfo.configure = null, so I can't use this as I  normally would do it
// 4) Save the appWidgetId or delete it again depending on if the user finished the setup or cancelled it
```

**Normal approach (not important for my use case, but generally describes how it works)**

- create a widget id and then use the `AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_PICK` intent to let the user pick a widget
- after selection, pass on the data to the `AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE` intent and use `intent.setComponent(appWidgetInfo.configure);`
- after setup, save the widget id (or delete it if the user canceled the setup) in my custom data and use the id to show and update the widget
- => For my case, this is working fine...

**Question**

How do I get a valid  `AppWidgetProviderInfo` with a configure field != null so that I can use following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE);
// appWidgetInfo.configure is null for appWidgetInfo received from mAppWidgetManager.getInstalledProviders()
// it is not if the appWidgetInfo is received via the AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_PICK intent...
intent.setComponent(appWidgetInfo.configure);
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, WIDGET_CONFIGURE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Or is there an alternative approach to this?

I think I somehow must create a widget with the `AppWidgetProviderInfo` manually and then reget the info with `mAppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(appWidgetId);` and then I will have a filled `configure` field as this seems to happen if I use `AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_PICK` intent, but I don't know I do this manually...

Answer (score 3):

I could solve the issue. The `ACTION_APPWIDGET_PICK` intent binds the widget to the id, so this must be done manually in my case:

```
private static void configureWidgetManually(AppCompatActivity activity, AppWidgetProviderInfo appWidgetInfo) {
    int appWidgetId = mAppWidgetHost.allocateAppWidgetId();

    boolean hasPermission = mAppWidgetManager.bindAppWidgetIdIfAllowed(appWidgetId, appWidgetInfo.provider);
    if (!hasPermission) {
         // this if part is untested, I never get into this part, but from my understanding it should work like this...
        Intent intent = new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_BIND);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_PROVIDER, appWidgetInfo.provider);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_PROVIDER_PROFILE, appWidgetInfo.getProfile());
        }
        // Result of this can be handled the same way as the result of AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_PICK, so we can even use the same request code...
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, WIDGET_SELECTOR_REQUEST_CODE);
    } else {
        // Widget is bound, we can continue as if we would have used the `AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_PICK` intent
        appWidgetInfo = mAppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(appWidgetId);
        configureWidget(activity, appWidgetId, appWidgetInfo);
    }
}

private static void configureWidget(AppCompatActivity activity, int appWidgetId, AppWidgetProviderInfo appWidgetInfo) {

    if (appWidgetInfo.configure != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE);
        intent.setComponent(appWidgetInfo.configure);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, WIDGET_CONFIGURE_REQUEST_CODE);
    } else {
        // widget is configured, do whatever you want with the id...
    }
}
```